We are unable to create multiple subnets using terraform under the same vnet using a cvs as input file
`We are seeing below error while creating multiple subnets in the same vnets. Could someone please guide me how to achieve this. And would like to know if we can use the csv inputs as variable please post your suggestions here. Thankyou
azureuser@aztfserver:\~/az_csv_tasks_new$ sudo terraform apply  -auto-approve
╷
│ Error: Duplicate object key
│
│   on rg_vnets_subnets.tf line 24, in resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg":
│   24:   for_each = { for v in local.vnet_config : v.resource_group_name =\> v }
│     ├────────────────
│     │ v.resource_group_name is "rg-ScriptTest-wus-002"
│
│ Two different items produced the key "rg-ScriptTest-wus-002" in this 'for' expression. If         duplicates are expected, use the  
│ ellipsis (...) after the value expression to enable grouping by key.

After updating the ellipsis (...) we are seeing this error

azureuser@aztfserver:~/az_csv_tasks_new$ sudo terraform apply  -auto-approve
│ Error: Duplicate object key
│
│   on rg_vnets_subnets.tf line 24, in resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg":
│   24:   for_each = { for v in local.vnet_config : v.resource_group_name => v }
│     ├────────────────
│     │ v.resource_group_name is "rg-ScriptTest-wus-002"
│
│ Two different items produced the key "rg-ScriptTest-wus-002" in this 'for' expression. If duplicates are expected, use the
│ ellipsis (...) after the value expression to enable grouping by key.
╵
azureuser@aztfserver:~/az_csv_tasks_new$

Below is the configuration file.
cat rg_vnets_subnets.csv

resource_group_name,location,vnet_name,vnet_address_space,subnet_name,subnet_address_space
rg-ScriptTest-eus-001,East US,vnet-ScriptTest-eus-001,10.0.0.0/16,subnet1,10.0.1.0/26
rg-ScriptTest-wus-002,West US,vnet-ScriptTest-wus-002,11.0.0.0/16,subnet2,11.0.1.0/26
rg-ScriptTest-wus-002,West US,vnet-ScriptTest-wus-002,11.0.0.0/16,subnet3,11.0.2.0/26

#cat main.tf
locals {
  vnet_config = csvdecode(file("${path.module}/rg_vnets_subnets.csv"))
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  for_each = { for v in local.vnet_config : v.resource_group_name => v }
  name     = each.value.resource_group_name
  location = each.value.location
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet" {
  for_each            = { for v in local.vnet_config : v.vnet_name => v }
  name                = each.value.vnet_name
  location            = each.value.location
  resource_group_name = each.value.resource_group_name
  address_space       = [each.value.vnet_address_space]
  depends_on          = [azurerm_resource_group.rg]
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnet" {
  for_each            = { for v in local.vnet_config : "${v.vnet_name}-${v.subnet_name}" => v }
  name                = each.value.subnet_name
  resource_group_name = each.value.resource_group_name
  virtual_network_name = each.value.vnet_name
 address_prefixes     = [each.value.subnet_address_space]
 depends_on          = [azurerm_virtual_network.vnet]
}

enter image description here

Just out of curiosity, is there any good reason why you need to use a CSV file as input?
